# Is it possible to start method chaining on a new line after a variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of `.on()` methods that I'd like to chain and align. I'm afraid that the interpreter might insert a semicolon after a variable name in this example:

```
var foo = new Bar();

foo // Semicolon insertion here.
  .on()
  .on();
```

Is there a way to keep this structure, or should I avoid doing it? Thank you!

Comment: Easiest way to find out is just to write some code like that and see if it runs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Semi-colons are not inserted on lines preceding a line that starts with a `.`

You can safely start method / property chaining on new lines.

```
objectName
    .method1()
    .property
    .method2();
```